# Can i start download automatically when click on wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress, download

My question is very simple (maybe its difficult).

In my wordpress blog, it's possible to start a download when a visitor click on a simple post? (obviusley the same download).

It"s very difficult for me :/

Do you have any tips&tricks?

It's requires PHP or not?

```
<?php
echo "something to do";
?>
```

i have already tried a lot of plugin but nothing do this things
i have some difficult with this way

thanks a lot for the writer
best regards